# Multiple validations on a form element does not work when using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

am using material ui for my website ui and also using react-hook-form. My code is as:

```
<TextField
            name="firstName"
            id="firstName"
            label="First Name"
            ref={register({ required: true, minLength: 6 })}
          />
          <div>
            {errors.firstName?.type === "required" && (
              <div className={classes.errorMsg}>First Name is required.</div>
            )}
            {errors.firstName?.type === "minLength" && (
              <div className={classes.errorMsg}>
                First Name length should be more than 6 characters.
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
```

I am trying to apply multiple validations on firstName element but only 'required' is working. I enter any value less than 6 characters then react-hook-form should show 'minLength' error which is not working.

Kindly suggest me this is an issue of react-hook-form or i am doing something wrong to apply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think react-hook-form does not support to Material-Ui's < Textfield /> element. If I use < Input /> tag instead of < Textfield /> tag then multiple validations work while react-hook-form says that it supports Material-UI. Kindly suggest what is the solution of this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inputRef instead of ref

```
<TextField
    name="firstName"
    id="firstName"
    label="First Name"
    inputRef={register({ required: true, minLength: 6 })}
  />
```